# Mutliple Wordpress loops in one page, produces same data

Tags: php, html, wordpress, filter

I'm having an issue with using more than one loop in the `header.php` file. The issue is that all sections display the results of the final loop and not their own. Here is my code:

```
        <div class="catagory active face">
          <?php /*-- Body --*/
            $args01 = array('post_type' => 'services','category' => 'face',);
            $loop01 = new WP_Query( $args01 );
            if ( $loop01->have_posts() ) :
              while ( $loop01->have_posts() ) : $loop01->the_post();
                echo '<p><a class="text-white" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
              endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
          ?>
        </div>

        <div class="catagory hide breast">
          <?php /*-- Body --*/
            $args02 = array('post_type' => 'services','category' => 'breast',);
            $loop02 = new WP_Query( $args02 );
            if ( $loop02->have_posts() ) :
              while ( $loop02->have_posts() ) : $loop02->the_post();
                echo '<p><a class="text-white" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
              endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
          ?>
        </div>

        <div class="catagory hide body">
          <?php /*-- Body --*/
            $args03 = array('post_type' => 'services','category' => 'body',);
            $loop03 = new WP_Query( $args03 );
            if ( $loop03->have_posts() ) :
              while ( $loop03->have_posts() ) : $loop03->the_post();
                echo '<p><a class="text-white" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
              endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
          ?>
        </div>
```

Any ideas as to why the first two loops displays the third loops result? What am I missing here?

Comment: Hope you are using custom taxonomy as category - can I know the taxonomy name?

Comment: While the code you've shown should work, it's not possible to troubleshoot well without seeing the "section loop" code that you indicate always shows the same content as the last loop above (assuming you mean `$loop03` code).  Note that you don't need to use unique names for the args / loops in your code above, in fact it would conserve some memory if you would re-use them (just call it `$args`, and simply assign the new array of arguments to it each time.  And just call it `$loop`, and assign it to the new `WP_Query` each time).

Comment: Hi @cale_b Yes, I'll do that. It was like that originally, but I assumed that was the error, where all the vars were all the same. But that wasn't the case.

Comment: Can you add the code from the section that isn't working properly, so it's possible to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code

```
<div class="catagory active face">
  <?php 
      $args01 = array('post_type' => 'services',
                      'tax_query' => array(
                                     array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy_name',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => 'face' 
                                      )));
      $loop01 = new WP_Query( $args01 );   
      if ( $loop01->have_posts() ) :
          while ( $loop01->have_posts() ) : $loop01->the_post();
            echo '<p><a class="text-white" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
          endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
      endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="catagory hide breast">
  <?php 
      $args02 = array('post_type' => 'services',
                      'tax_query' => array(
                                      array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy_name',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => 'breast' 
                                      )));
      $loop02 = new WP_Query( $args02 );
      if ( $loop02->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop02->have_posts() ) : $loop02->the_post();
          echo '<p><a class="text-white" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
      endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="catagory hide body">
  <?php 
      $args03 = array('post_type' => 'services',
                      'tax_query' => array(
                                      array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy_name',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => 'body' 
                                      )));
      $loop03 = new WP_Query( $args03 );
      if ( $loop03->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop03->have_posts() ) : $loop03->the_post();
          echo '<p><a class="text-white" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
      endif; ?>
</div>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful, especially when it's this big of a block of code, and you've not commented the code.  What did you change? Why should it work?

Comment: I have tested at my end then i have post this answer as its working the way questioner wants

Comment: Hi @raju_eww I used the code you suggested and created a taxonomy called 'services' and attached it to the 'services' category, but it doesn't seem to pull any data. :(

Comment: it will conflict with your post_type if you name custom taxonomy as `services` so please use your current taxonomy slug dont add my custom taxonomy services

Comment: for testing purposr i have created taxonomy `services` but in my case `post_type` name was different

Comment: but in your case there is name of post-type which is `services` you can't give name of taxonomy as `services`

Comment: you already have your taxonomy there so you have created categories in it so just add your `taxonomy-name` there

Comment: @raju_eww I've tried changing the taxonomy and linked it to the 'services' category. This is my updated code, but it seems to still not pull any data: https://i.imgur.com/gPZBv6z.png

Comment: `service_category` is your taxonomy slug and also `face` `body` `breast` are its categories first make sure that

Comment: @raju_eww Gotcha, is this correct then when setting up the taxonomy? https://i.imgur.com/jkRoHom.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176730/discussion-between-raju-eww-and-charlie-mcshane).

Comment: After discussing this, I have managed to get the code working with Raju_Eww's code. Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should move `wp_reset_postdata();` to *after* `endif;` in all loops

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately the same result still. :(

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```html
<div class="catagory active face">
          <?php /*-- Body --*/
            $do_not_duplicate = array();
            $args01 = array('post_type' => 'services','category' => 'face',);
            $loop01 = new WP_Query( $args01 );
            if ( $loop01->have_posts() ) :
              while ( $loop01->have_posts() ) : $loop01->the_post();
                $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
                echo '<p><a class="text-white" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
              endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
          ?>
        </div>

        <div class="catagory hide breast">
          <?php /*-- Body --*/
            $args02 = array('post_type' => 'services','category' => 'breast',);
            $loop02 = new WP_Query( $args02 );
            if ( $loop02->have_posts() ) :
              while ( $loop02->have_posts() ) : $loop02->the_post();
                $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; 
                echo '<p><a class="text-white" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
              endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
            endif; 
          ?>
        </div>

        <div class="catagory hide body">
          <?php /*-- Body --*/
            $args03 = array('post_type' => 'services','category' => 'body',);
            $loop03 = new WP_Query( $args03 );
            if ( $loop03->have_posts() ) :
              while ( $loop03->have_posts() ) : $loop03->the_post();
                $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; 
                echo '<p><a class="text-white" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
              endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
          ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: I tried it out, but unfortunately it was the same result. Thank you for the suggestion however!

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful, especially when it's this big of a block of code, and you've not commented the code. What did you change? Why should it work?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using custom taxonomy as category and so you need to use 'taxonomy' query. Use the code below and loop as needed.

```
<?php
$tax01 = array('taxonomy' => 'service_category','terms' =>5); // replace taxonmy name & id here
$args01 = array('post_type' => 'services','tax_query' => array($tax01));
$loop01 = new WP_Query( $args01 );
if ( $loop01->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $loop01->have_posts() ) : $loop01->the_post();
        echo '<p><a class="text-white" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: I haven't got a taxonomy setup with 'Services'. But I'm using Custom Post Types UI plugin, I could add it? What process/steps should I take when creating it as a taxonomy as well?

Comment: I am suggesting to go with taxonomies since WordPress default posts 'category' would be shared if you select 'Categories' from 'Built-in Taxonomies' section of the plugin. You can add the taxonomy easily as instructed in https://docs.buddyforms.com/article/153-create-a-new-post-type-and-taxonomy-with-the-cpt-ui-plugin. Feel free to change the 'taxonomy name' in the above code.